# Nvidia-current brocken dependency

Tags: nvidia

I tried install nvidia driver

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-current : Depends: nvidia-304 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.

user@host:$ install nvidia-304
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 nvidia-304 : Depends: lib32gcc1 but it is not going to be installed
              Depends: libc6-i386 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

But it have broken dependency. How install nvidia driver properly?